# Incorrectly displayed view created programmatically (android)

Tags: java, android, xml, styles

I create some views programmatically, but on some  devices they are displayed wrong. I have Layout in which i programmatically add spinner. This is my xml:

`container` - it's layout where i create spinner (programmatically)

`spinnerL` - here i add spinner

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#26ffffff"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/spinnerL"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/spinnerOpen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinnerImage"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />



        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Here i create and add the spinner:

```
//here i set margins
View linearLayoutG = convertView.findViewById(R.id.container);

linearLayoutG.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#26ffffff"));

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layoutParams.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 30);
linearLayoutG.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

//here i create spinner
View linearLayout = convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerL);
final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(context);

spinner.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

//code

((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(spinner);
```

(sorry about links, i don't have 15 reputation)

Result on [android 4.0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2zk7.jpg)

Result on [android 5+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTkTi.jpg)

If i use static size, like this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 120);
```

Here's what happens

Result on [android 4.0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6BMR.jpg)

Result on [android 5+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMpFZ.jpg)

Comment: Result code in **device 4.0.1** http://i.stack.imgur.com/s6BMR.jpg
Result code in **android 5+** http://i.stack.imgur.com/pMpFZ.jpg

Comment: Just to understand your question. Your problem is is that WRAP_CONTENT does not work on android 5+ as expected? (in your sample)

Comment: @oberflansch yes, it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as i can see in your code :

```
spinner.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

you are setting the height to `MATCH_PARENT`. I have no idea why it is working on **4.0.1** but change your code to this:

```
spinner.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```